# Скрестить/напечатать два текста разных цветов в pillow (Python)

Tags: python, pillow

**Ситуация такая** - у меня есть текст, вводимый пользователем и есть текст генерируемый рандомно. Они разного цвета и поэтому не получится обойтись просто знаком «+»

**Цель** - напечатать на фото оба эти текста друг за другом, аля второе дополнение первого.

**Как это сделать?** куски кода ниже, вот их и надо склеить в одну строку

```
idraw.text((sy, 365), name_one, "black", font=font3, align="left")
idraw.text((sy, 528), name_two, "black", font=font3,align="left")

idraw.text((sk, 365), a, "grey", font=font3)
idraw.text((sk, 528), b, "grey", font=font3)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Второй текст можно подвинуть на длину первого. Вычислить ее можно с помощью `textlength()`.

```
name_one_lenght = idraw.textlength(name_one, font=font3)
name_two_lenght = idraw.textlength(name_two, font=font3)
```

В координатах второго текста используем координату первого текста и его длину

```
idraw.text((sy, 365), name_one, "black", font=font3, align="left")
idraw.text((sy, 528), name_two, "black", font=font3, align="left")

idraw.text((sy + name_one_lenght, 365), a, "grey", font=font3)
idraw.text((sy + name_two_lenght, 528), b, "grey", font=font3)
```